# Cannot link boost.python with mingw

Tags: python, boost, mingw

I have already build boost.python lib by mingw,Got two lib files:

- libboost_python-mgw45-mt-1_46_1.a
- libboost_python-mgw45-mt-d-1_46_1.a

But I cant link these libs in my test programs.And the other components like regex works fine.I dont know how to solve this.

my user-config.jam:

```
using python
     : 2.7
     : F:\\Programs\\Python\\python # cmd-or-prefix
     : F:\\Programs\\Python\\include
     : F:\\Programs\\Python\\lib
     : <toolset>gcc # condition
     ;
```

and the build command:
bjam toolset=gcc --with-python

My Enviroment:

- python 2.7
- mingw 4.5.1
- boost 1.46.1
- OS:windows xp

Hope I explained my problem clearly, I'm not english native speaker.
Any advise will be appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why (and I never really cared enough to dig for the reason), but Boost.Python refuses to link statically on Windows. This is easily solved, though — just rebuild it as a DLL (`bjam toolset=gcc --with-python link=shared`).